# How to rename an existing custom table in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, database, table, upgradeschema

I created a table with name **"Redeem_blanace"** using InstallSchema.php as:

```
class InstallSchema implements InstallSchemaInterface
{
    /**
    * {@inheritdoc}
    * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveMethodLength)
    */
    public function install(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {


      $setup->startSetup();

      $table = $setup->getConnection()->newTable($setup->getTable('Redeem_balance')
      )->addColumn(
        'transaction_id',
        Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
        null,
        ['identity' => true, 'unsigned' => true, 'nullable' => false, 'primary' =>true],
        'Transaction_Id'
      )->addColumn(
        'gift_code',
        Table::TYPE_TEXT,
        255,
        ['nullable' => true],
        'Gift_Code'
      )->addColumn(
        'redeem_amount',
        \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_DECIMAL,
          '20,4',
          ['nullable' => false, 'default' => 0],
        'Redeem_Amount'
      )->addColumn(
          'date_expires',
          Table::TYPE_TEXT,
          null,
          ['nullable' => true],
          'Date_Expires'
      )->addColumn(
        'expired_amount',
        Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
        null,
        ['unsigned' => false, 'nullable' => false],
        'Expired_Amount'
      )->addIndex(
        $setup->getIdxName('Redeem_balance', ['transaction_id']),
        ['transaction_id']
      )->setComment(
        'Redeem Balance Tracking Table'
      );
      $setup->getConnection()->createTable($table);

      $setup->endSetup();


      }
}
```

I wanted to change the table name to **"pme_customerbalance"**
How can I do this ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can create **UpgradeSchema.php** file in your module and add below content in that file

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Setup/UpgradeSchema.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;

class UpgradeSchema implements UpgradeSchemaInterface
{
    public function upgrade(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $setup->startSetup();
        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.0.2', '<')) {
            $setup->getConnection()->renameTable($setup->getTable('Redeem_balance'), $setup->getTable('pme_customerbalance'));
        }
        $setup->endSetup();
    }
}
```

You can change module version based on your module.

Hope this will help you!

Comment: Yes, it worked.